# Neo4J Cypher Hanging on Read

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm experiencing a situation where my application is hanging when trying to execute a cypher query.  The queries are selecting a single node based on index and unique key.

Example Query:

```
"MATCH (object:GRAPH_OBJECT {`zeusportal.graph.node.id`: {objectid} }) RETURN object.`zeusportal.graph.node.id` AS objectid"
```

I'm not seeing any threads that are actively trying to write to the node in question, but multiple threads are hanging when trying to read the result of the Cypher query.

I have a thread monitor that is observing what is being executed.  Here is the thread dump:

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.concurrent.LockWaitStrategies$3.apply(LockWaitStrategies.java:69)
org.neo4j.kernel.ha.lock.forseti.ForsetiClient.acquireShared(ForsetiClient.java:179)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodeGetUniqueFromIndexLookup(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:235)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeGetUniqueFromIndexLookup(OperationsFacade.java:180)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_2.TransactionBoundQueryContext.exactUniqueIndexSearch(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:134)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.exactUniqueIndexSearch(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:96)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$super$exactUniqueIndexSearch(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:131)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$exactUniqueIndexSearch$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:131)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$exactUniqueIndexSearch$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:131)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:182)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.exactUniqueIndexSearch(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:131)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.NodeIndexSeekPipe$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NodeIndexSeekPipe.scala:45)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.NodeIndexSeekPipe$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NodeIndexSeekPipe.scala:45)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.commands.indexQuery$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(indexQuery.scala:53)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.commands.indexQuery$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(indexQuery.scala:51)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.commands.indexQuery$.apply(indexQuery.scala:50)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.NodeIndexSeekPipe.internalCreateResults(NodeIndexSeekPipe.scala:55)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.Pipe$class.createResults(Pipe.scala:54)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.NodeIndexSeekPipe.createResults(NodeIndexSeekPipe.scala:33)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:115)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:92)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:64)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:122)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:106)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.run(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:70)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:166)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:166)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.exceptionHandlerFor2_2$.runSafely(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:104)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:165)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:27)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:107)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:101)
org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ServerExecutionEngine.java:61)
org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:953)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.graph.GraphManagerProxy.getObjectHelper(GraphManagerProxy.java:743)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.graph.GraphManagerProxy.getObject(GraphManagerProxy.java:710)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.management.TemplateManagerImpl.getTemplate(TemplateManagerImpl.java:100)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.management.TemplateManagerImpl.getTemplate(TemplateManagerImpl.java:105)
org.apache.jsp.zpindex_jsp._jspService(zpindex_jsp.java:153)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:112)
org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DecoratorFilter.doFilter(DecoratorFilter.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.display.BodyTag.doStartTag(BodyTag.java:70)
org.apache.jsp.jspincludes.body_jsp._jspx_meth_portal_005fbody_005f0(body_jsp.java:150)
org.apache.jsp.jspincludes.body_jsp._jspService(body_jsp.java:120)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:112)
org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DecoratorFilter.doFilter(DecoratorFilter.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jsp.jspincludes.content_jsp._jspService(content_jsp.java:171)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:112)
org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DecoratorFilter.doFilter(DecoratorFilter.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.ZplFilter.doFilter(ZplFilter.java:227)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.setup.SetupFilter.doFilter(SetupFilter.java:35)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.WhosOnlineFilter.doFilter(WhosOnlineFilter.java:36)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.WhosOnlineFilter.doFilter(WhosOnlineFilter.java:24)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.ServletMappingFilter.doFilter(ServletMappingFilter.java:84)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.ServletMappingFilter.doFilter(ServletMappingFilter.java:26)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DecoratorFilter.doFilter(DecoratorFilter.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.URLToObjectFilter.doFilter(URLToObjectFilter.java:95)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.URLToObjectFilter.doFilter(URLToObjectFilter.java:26)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:51)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:23)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.CreateAuthFilter.doFilter(CreateAuthFilter.java:113)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.CreateAuthFilter.doFilter(CreateAuthFilter.java:29)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:59)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.OneWebAppMultiDomainFilter.doFilter(OneWebAppMultiDomainFilter.java:123)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.OneWebAppMultiDomainFilter.doFilter(OneWebAppMultiDomainFilter.java:38)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DBSingleConnectionPerThreadFilter.doFilter(DBSingleConnectionPerThreadFilter.java:36)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DBConnectionMonitorFilter.doFilter(DBConnectionMonitorFilter.java:34)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.DBConnectionMonitorFilter.doFilter(DBConnectionMonitorFilter.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.ThreadMonitorFilter.doFilter(ThreadMonitorFilter.java:42)
com.enetexperience.zeusportal.servlets.filters.ThreadMonitorFilter.doFilter(ThreadMonitorFilter.java:83)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have the 'id' property indexed?  If not and you have a lot of nodes (e.g. millions), that will take quite a while as it needs to scan through every node looking for that id.

Comment: I don't have millions of nodes, and I have a unique index set on the 'id' property.  The deadlock doesn't happen all the time, but when it does the entire application comes to a halt if multiple requests try to request that node.

Comment: The stack trace is showing that Neo4J is making a call to Thread.sleep() which is hanging the thread that is executing the Cypher

Comment: Which neo4j version are you using? Can you share the full thread dump of your app? Are you executing write operations concurrently which either are long running or not closing transactions?

Comment: I was using Neo4j 2.2.  When I can reproduce the error I can share the threads that are running.  I didn't see any other threads running and doing a write at the same time, but I do have Quartz jobs running that operate on Neo4j.  Checking to see if there are places where transactions were not closed.